# Add ComboBoxItem from MS Access Database

Tags: java

I am trying to add ComboxItem from database. I have write the code given below. When I run the program it give a error message.

Message is
java.sql.SQLException:Driver does not support this function

someone please help me.

here is my code

```
public class DepositFirstForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection conn=null;
    ResultSet rst=null;
    PreparedStatement pst=null;
    private void ItemComb(){

private void ItemComb(){

    String sql="SELECT * FROM account_type";

    try
    {
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rst=pst.executeQuery(sql);
         while(rst.next()){  

             String actype=rst.getString("account_type");
             dfcmb1.addItem(actype);

        } 


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }

}
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEventevt)                           {                                  
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    conn=Connect.connectDB();
    ItemComb();


}

}
```

my table name is account_type

```
serial_no   account_type

1       regular
2       premium
3       golden
```

Comment: On what line do you get the error? When you're tying to retrieve the item from the ResultSet? Also, remember to close the statement and connection after you're done with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the (sql) parameter from you call to pst.executeQuery:

```
rst = pst.executeQuery();
```

Since your PreparedStatement is already created using the SQL.
I trust you are declaring conn, pst and rst somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I have removed (sql) parameter as you suggested and it's working.